# Convert in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is in SQL SERVER 2012 environment I have the following problem , i have a table with a field with type `datetime`.

This field is like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:msmsms` - "2013-12-12 00:00:00.000"

And i need to extract `yyyy` to one field. `mm` for another one and `dd` for the last one.

I tried to do this

```
SELECT        distinct CONVERT(CHAR (10), Data, 120) as Dia, 
 CONVERT(CHAR (7), Data, 120) as Mes, 
CONVERT(CHAR (4), Data, 120) as Ano
FROM            Vendas
```

but the output i get is

```
Day 12-12-2013
Month 12-2013
Year 2013
```

The year is correct but i can't find a way to just cut the right part for Day and Month.

Somebody could help me please ?

Comment: Are your target fields numeric or character?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT YEAR(Data), MONTH(Data), DAY(Data) FROM dbo.Vendas;
```

or

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, Data), DATEPART(MONTH, Data), DATEPART(DAY, Data)
  FROM dbo.Vendas;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3597/1)**

Comment: @Emanuel Well, you need to provide a little more info, then. You could start with what "does not work" means.

Comment: @EmanuelBicho I just got the result I expected with the following: `SELECT YEAR(GetDate()), MONTH(GetDate()), DAY(GetDate())` . That looks a lot like what Aaron suggested.

Comment: I have one table that one of the field's is in the format datetime as i posted.Now i need to extract day month and year to another field's.

Comment: @EmanuelBicho You're going to have to describe the problem a bit better than that, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for trying to helping me, but is just like i have posted. One table with one field with format datetime. And i have in my DataWarehouse 3 fields ( day month and year) and i need to extract  the day month and year from the field with datetime type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `YEAR` , `MONTH` and `DAY` functions to extract the required parts from your DATETIME Column something like this ...

```
DECLARE @DateColumn DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT  YEAR(@DateColumn)  AS [Year]
       ,MONTH(@DateColumn) AS [Month]
       ,DAY(@DateColumn)   AS [Day]
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═════╗
║ Year ║ Month ║ Day ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═════╣
║ 2014 ║     2 ║   5 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═════╝
```

**Query for your Table**

```
SELECT  YEAR(Data)  AS [Year]
       ,MONTH(Data) AS [Month]
       ,DAY(Data)   AS [Day]
FROM Vendas
```

Comment: that does not work too, i am in Microsfot Visual Studio , making an ETL solution and i need to extract the data as you could see in my post, but the problem i have is with convert that just get's where it starts to read , and reads until the end of the field

Comment: This WORKS ,THANK YOU SO MUCH and all the people who tried to help me . Thanks

Comment: Not a problem @EmanuelBicho if it helped you, you can accept it as an answer :)

Comment: I'm sure this is a classic PEBKAC situation

Comment: lol @PEBKAC situation didnt know what it means had to google it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', CONVERT(varchar(2), getdate(), 101) --Month Part
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', CONVERT(varchar(4), getdate(), 102) --Year Part
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', CONVERT(varchar(2), getdate(), 103) --Day Part
```

or

```
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', MONTH(GETDATE()) --Month Part
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', year(GETDATE()) --Year Part
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', day(GETDATE()) --Day Part
```

or

```
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', RIGHT('0'+CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)),2) --Month Part
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', RIGHT('0'+CAST(year(GETDATE()) AS varchar(4)),4) --Year Part
SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', RIGHT('0'+CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)), 2) --Day Part
```

or

```
SELECT month('2014-12-23') --Month Part 
SELECT year('2014-12-23') --Year Part
SELECT day('2014-12-23') --Day Part
```